# How do you execute the code inside a nested for-loop only for the instance when a condition is met?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm using a nested for-loop to compare the items in an array to other items within the same array. Once a particular condition is met concerning the items being compared, I want to discontinue the loop and push those two items into a different array. The problem is, however, that when the condition is met it will push those two items into the array for the number of iterations in the nested loop. How would I go about only pushing those items into the new array for the one time the condition is met?

I've already attempted to break out of the initial for-loop but this doesn't seem to do anything.

```
outer_loop:

for (let i = 0; i < varifiedKeypoints.length; i++) {

  let initialKeypoint = varifiedKeypoints[i];

  for (let j = 0; j < varifiedKeypoints.length; j++) {

    let comparisonKeypoint = varifiedKeypoints[j];

    if (initialKeypoint.part != comparisonKeypoint.part) {

      if (Math.abs(comparisonKeypoint.position.x - initialKeypoint.position.x) <= 20
      && Math.abs(comparisonKeypoint.position.y - initialKeypoint.position.y) <= 20) {

        if (keypointsCompatible(initialKeypoint.part, comparisonKeypoint.part)) {

          console.log("Activating part: " + initialKeypoint.part);
          console.log("Activated part: " + comparisonKeypoint.part);

          let keypointPair = {
            point_1: initialKeypoint.part,
            point_2: comparisonKeypoint.part
          }

          console.log("Pushing parts!");
          activeParts.push(keypointPair);

          console.log("breaking loop!");
          break outer_loop;

          console.log("Loop broken - NOT!!!")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So just use a [`break` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) if you want to break the loop?

Answer (score 1):

Add this above your first for loop

```
outer_loop:
```

Then in your condition break out with

```
break outer_loop;
```

Comment: Hey Matthew, as I had mentioned I had tried this and it didn't seem to work. I've updated my code to reflect this.

Comment: @user2724072 In your code have you wrapped it all in brackets .... outer_loop: {   all your code }  , not sure if I'm getting this right ?